# Finding out number of pixels in white area in binary image as well as number of pixels of ROI in original image in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have segmented image in which my region of interest (ROI) was white color cotton. Now I want to compare the number of pixels in segmented area i.e. total number of pixels in white blob in binary image with actual number of pixels of ROI in actual image. How I can do that. Following figure can clear the point.
[image][image]

As we can see from original image, my ROI was white color cotton circled in red boundry. When I segmented this image I got binary image as shown. As we can noticed there are some missing areas in binary image as compare to original area. So, I want to count the number of pixels in original image of ROI and number of pixels of white blob in binary image. So that I can calculate difference in actual pixels of ROI and actual segmented number of pixels.

Thank You.

Comment: To compute the number of pixels in the binary image just use `sum(bin_img(:) > 0);` assuming a single channel image. I can't tell you how to compute the number of pixels in the true ROI without knowing how the true ROI is stored. Please provide a description or example of the true ROI.

Comment: The only way I see you getting the actual number of pixels in ROI of original image is modifying the image in a program like paint to black out (brush) the pixels you are not interested in. Then segment that image again by looking at non-black pixels (you can choose pink if you want) and perform the operation that jodag described.

Comment: Thanks @jodag , for reply. I stored image as RGB and white cotton area is my ROI. In above true picture, ROI marked by red boundary. I want to find out the number of pixels of this ROI. My True ROI  is white cotton shown in true image.

Comment: Thanks @AntonSavelyev for the reply. Method what you suggest is time-consuming as I have 60 images so I can do this to each image separately. What I am thinking is: Is there any way like I draw boundaries around ROI in true image and it automatically calculates the number of pixels in that enclosed boundaries.

Comment: @NaseebGill Will you be the one drawing the boundaries? Or do you want MATLAB to do it?

Comment: @AntonSavelyev I will draw boundaries in the true image as precisely as I can using mouse  and then want to know the number of pixels inside those boundaries using MATLAB.

Comment: To draw the boundaries yourself you should use a cropping tool in an image editing software and just copy-paste the cropped section onto a black canvas and save that image. Definetely more time consuming and depending on the accuracy you require, you might be able to get away with the method (or a tweaked version) I posted in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to not draw the boundaries yourself, you can try this. It might not be as precise as you need, but you might get close to the actual value by tweaking with the thresholding values I used (100 for all 3 channels in this case).

Assume I is your original image. First create the binary mask by thresholding with the RGB values. Then remove all the small objects that don't have at least a 2000 pixel area. Then sum up the pixels of that object.

```
IT = I(:,:,1) > 100;
IT(I(:,:,2) < 100) = 0;
IT(I(:,:,3) < 100) = 0;
IT = bwareaopen(IT, 2000);
sum(IT(:) > 0)
```

> 21380

Resulting image: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Anton Savelyev. Basically, what you did in above code was if for any pixel Red component > 100 and Blue, Green < 100, that pixel become white else black. For few images, It worked perfectly. But, I have plenty of images in various illumination conditions and above code create errors in many cases .  I developed algorithm to detect white color in  varying illuminations.  I want to compare white object pixels in true image and white object pixels in  segmented image. Their difference will be error in segmentation. So I need to be defined white object in true image precisely with hand.

Comment: In that case, you will need to use an image editing software as I described in my other comment.

Comment: Yes, Now, I am using Adobe photoshop for the same. I convert white object as foreground and rest of all as background. Background will be black in color and later on, in Matlab, I can count the white pixels. This process may give me some desired results. I hope so.